# Why does this script never run?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've got the following JavaScript statement, that executes on Page Load:

The variable `u1` is populated with one of the following values:

`BBSLoan|Accept|PPI+No|60Months`
`BBSLoan|Refer|PPI+No|60Months`
`HSBSLoan|Accept|PPI+No|48Months`
`HSBSLoan|Refer|PPI+No|48Months`

I have been informed that the conditions in the conditional statements will never be met - is this true? From what I can see, going on each of the variables, the index that will be returned by `indexOf` is `0`? Unless I am mistaken?

EDIT: Just to clarify, the variable 'u1' will be populated dynamically with any of the 4 strings listed above. The `%pu1=!;` is actually a macro that will populate this value.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var u1 = '%pu1=!;';

    if (u1.indexOf('BBSLoan|Accept') > -1) {
        var pvnPixel = '<img src="http://www.url1.com"/>';
        document.writeln(pvnPixel);
    }
    if (u1.indexOf('BBSLoan|Refer') > -1) {
        var pvnPixel2 = '<img src="https://www.url2.com;"/>';
        document.writeln(pvnPixel2);
    }
    if (u1.indexOf('HSBSLoan|Accept') > -1) {
        var pvnPixel3 = '<img src="https://www.url3.com;"/>';
        document.writeln(pvnPixel3);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `var u1 = '%pu1=!;';`? If you substitue one of your strings it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mDSgY/1/

Comment: @j08691 Exactly my point. I've edited my post to say this is a macro that populates the value with one of the 4 strings above. I can see that it works when the values are substituted too, hence why I'm confused!

Comment: Is your macro code not working? As evinced by the jsFiddle, the code you've posted (minus the `var u1 = '%pu1=!;';` chunk) works, so either you have other code conflicting with this, or the macro code is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally got this to work using `search` instead of `indexOf`!

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Just to clarify, the variable 'u1' will be populated dynamically with any of the 4 strings listed above. The %pu1=!; is actually a macro that will populate this value.

**This answer is not correct. It will be deleted later, but is being left to prevent this answer from popping up again.**

```
var u1 = '%pu1=!;';
```

The value of u1 is always `'%pu1=!;'`, since you declare it as that.

Comment: No actually this is part of a DoubleClick Floodlight Tag and that value is populated dynamically when the page loads. The `%pu1=!;1 is actually a macro that pulls in any of the values I listed above. Sorry should have made this clearer.

Comment: I would bet that the macro is failing. At least, that's what I would check first. What is the value of `u1` if you look at it at runtime?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo yes that's what I thought but the people that would be able to test this for me are saying there is nothing wrong with the macro!

Comment: You can test it yourself. Use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools (or whatever dev tools your browser of choice provides) and set a breakpoint.

Comment: It might also be that the macro is working just fine, but it's just running after this script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Would it make more sense to use a switch statement with a default case, or at a minimum provide an "else" with a default?

Have you tried to put a debugger statement in after var u1 is set, and step through using the client (firefox, chrome, IE, safari all have built in "developer tools" with the ability to step through js code) debugger to see what the value of u1 is?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because this is part of a DoubleClick Floodlight Tag which executes on page load. As far as I can see the syntax is correct but this doesn't fire for some reason.

Comment: can you console.log or alert the value?  Knowing the value when the page loads would help you to determine "why" the statements aren't working.