# Alternative to using search or indexOf

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706243/why-does-this-script-never-run).

I've got a JavaScript statement as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var u1 = '%pu1=!;';

if (u1.search('NBSLoan|Accept') > -1)
{       
var pvnPixel = '<img src="someurl.com"/>';
document.writeln(pvnPixel);
}
if (u1.indexOf('NBSLoan|Refer') > -1)
{       
var pvnPixel2 = '<img src="someurl2.com"/>';
document.writeln(pvnPixel2);
}
if (u1.indexOf('DeBSLoan|Accept') > -1) {
var pvnPixel3 = '<img src="someurl3.com"/>';
document.writeln(pvnPixel3);    
}
</script>
```

Given that the `u1` variable is a macro that may contain any of the following values:

`NBSLoan|Accept|PPI+No|48Months`
`NBSLoan|Refer|PPI+No|48Months`
`NBSLoan|Accept|PPI+No|48Months`
`NBSLoan|Refer|PPI+No|48Months`

Also bear in mind the last part (48 months) may change, how can I write a JavaScript statement that will only check the first part of the string? i.e. whether it is "NBSLoan|Accept" etc?

If you put the above statement in a JSFiddle, yes it does work but I assure you (in live) this isn't working so I'm exploring other possibilities of writing this statement. Could I do something like:

`if (u1.search(/NBSLoan|Accept/)`? Would this even work properly with pattern matching? At the moment what is happening is that if `u1` is equal to `NBSLoan|Accept` both url1 and url2 are being fired. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your parameters are delimited (seperated) by `|`'s, we can split on the `|`'s and check the bits between them, like this:

```
var u1 = '%pu1=!;';
var u1Split = u1.split("|");

if (u1Split[1] == "Accept") {
    var pvnPixel = '<img src="someurl.com"/>';
    document.writeln(pvnPixel);
} else if (u1Split[1]  == "Refer") {
    var pvnPixel2 = '<img src="someurl2.com"/>';
    document.writeln(pvnPixel2);
} else if (u1Split  == "Accept" && u1Split[0] == "DeBSLoan") {
    var pvnPixel3 = '<img src="someurl3.com"/>';
    document.writeln(pvnPixel3);
}
```

Let me know if that does the trick. Also, `writeln` isn't a standard function of `document` so if you haven't declared it previously somewhere, that would be another issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I'm gonna try this out. I could of course use document.write?

Comment: Right this isn't working. I'm getting an "illegal character" error on the last `}`?

Comment: @Kiz: Okay, I've edited my answer, try again. Copying code from jsFiddle often leaves you with an invisible character on the end of the code that Javascript doesn't like. I have no idea why and it's rather annoying. It should work now, though.